# Adding the image file to KML file using simplekml

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth, kmz, simplekml

I have made simple tool to convert CSV file containing latitude and logitude to KML　file.
Adding the image using the relative path is can be done easily for each location using following code:

`pnt.style.balloonstyle.text = "<![CDATA[ <table width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0> <tr><td><img  height = " + str(height_of_image_latlong) + "px width=" + str(width_of_image_latlong) + "px src='" + str(image_relative_folder) + "/" + str(row[0]) + ".JPG" + "' /></td></tr></table>]]>"`]

There is any way to save image permanently to the KML file not in the relative path,so that next time KML file will not loaded from file relative path but from own file system.